# Avoid running the process if page is refresh

Tags: oracle-apex

I am bit confuse how to achieve this not getting.

I have a page which as `interactive report` and one button called `trucate`.

In `interactive report` -> `selected table` : 'employee'
I Selected action as : `submit page` on button

So when click on button -> `truncate` -> The table gets truncated and interactive report does not show any details. It works as expected.

Now the problem is when I refresh again page the `PL/SQL` code gets run !!!. Need to avoid this on refresh it should not execute again

On button -> I have set the property -> `submit page`
Created the processing -> process -> PL/SQL code

**PL/SQL code**

```
declare 

m_count nnumber;

begin
     
select count(*) into m_count from employee;

if m_count > 0 then
      execute immediate 'truncate table employee';
      apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'truncated table !!!';
      commit;
else
     null; 
end if ;

exception 
     when others 
         then
                 apex_error.add_error(p_message => 'unable to load',p_display_location => apex_error.c_line_in_notification);


end;
```

Need you help on this

Comment: What is the button action ? Dynamic action or submit page ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie : Its a submit page

Comment: @KoenLostrie : If I don't use submit page ... I cannot display the inline message notification

Answer (score 0):

Set a server side condition of "When Button Pressed" on the pl/sql process. That should ensure it only runs when the button is clicked. However, the success message will be part of the url when after the page is submitted. So when you reload the page afterwards, the success message will be shown again.
What happens is the following

1. Render Page (first time)
2. Click Button to submit page
3. Run pl/sql in processing point "process". At this point the success message is set
4. Redirect the page (to same page number - it's just a reload). Since this is a redirect, all the information the page needs is in the actual url. That includes the success message generated in (3).

So... after (4) the url of the page is the page url that has the success message in the url itself. If the page is refreshed, then the message will be shown again. But the process will not re-run (since page is not re-submitted)

Comment: It does not work. Just try at your end. On page reload the same message is shown again and again

Comment: Ah yes. The message is shown but the process will not run when page is reloaded (you can verify by adding new data in another incognito browser session). Reason is that the message is part of the url of the page.

Comment: : Can you share me the application. I have no idea how to implement it. It would be great if you could demonstrate here it self with images

Comment: Updated my answer. Don't see an easy way to prevent msg from being shown on refresh for the reason I explained. Maybe others have better ideas.

Comment: Not happening any other method. After button click the same message comes

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that last comment. Please be more precise.

Comment: After clicking submit it gives me message like success. But when i reload page also gives me success message wihtout clicking button

Comment: Yes. That is what I explained in my updated answer. This is expected behavior.